# Definition of integration (high school level)

Tags: integration

I am learning integration at the moment and I have found two possible ways of defining integration.

The first one is by defining differentiation first as the slope of a curve. Then defining integration as the opposite of differentiation.

The second way is by defining integration as the area under a curve. Then showing that this definition implies that integration is the opposite of differentiation.

I feel like the second way makes more sense, because if we follow this way instead of the first one, we define both differentiation and integration in terms of their geometrical interpretation. Then we simply show that these two things which we have called "differentiation" and "integration" are actually opposites of each other. So this method has symmetry and seems to be more elegant to me. On the other hand, the first method feels uglier because it only defines differentiation in terms of geometry, then integration is kind of just "tacked on" to the definition of differentiation by saying that it is the opposite of it. Then somehow, it magically turns out that this thing we have called "integration" or "opposite of differentiation" is the area under a curve when interpreted geometrically.

I just feel like the way of defining both differentiation and integration in terms of geometry and only then showing that they are opposites of each other is more symmetrical and makes more sense.

So I have two questions really:

1. Being a high school level mathematician who doesn't understand advanced maths (analysis etc), could someone please intuitively explain which method is more mathematically "correct" and why? Or are both methods sound?
2. Also, is there a book that discusses these kinds of issues (ie the motivation behind different concepts) at a high school level? Or equivalently, a mathematical textbook that gives the motivation behind things? I heard that Spivak's "Calculus" (which I heard is really an analysis book rather than a calculus one) explains motivation, but I want a book that specifically explains motivation in the sense of "whence things originate" (as I have shown about integration) rather than just explaining shallow motivations such as how different concepts relate to each other or how to solve specific problems etc. In other words, I am looking for books that explain whence things originate from first principles, in the sense of "integration originates from the area under a curve" followed by a detailed explanation of how integration is defined from this, etc. Or are all mathematical textbooks beyond high school level like this? In other words, should I just wait until I start learning university level maths?

Comment: Both methods are correct, but historically, calculating the area under a curve and constructing the tangent to a curve were separate geometric problems for centuries, until Newton and Leibniz realized they were connected.  This was a great miracle at the time, I believe.  

I don't have a reference for you, unfortunately.

Comment: The second one is more intuitive and much easier to explain to anyone who does know anything in mathematics. Be sure that this is not a joke : I explain integration this way to my wife who, after 54 years of marriage, still don't understand anything in mathematics. When you think about the area, you expect a *number* as a result and not an *equation*.

Comment: One way of trying to clarify your understanding is to improve the precision of your prose. Start by distinguishing between indefinite integration and definite integration. Definite integration results in a number or an equation in a variable other than the integration variable. We don't normally use the terms indefinite and definite differentiation. But (definite) differentiation is finding the slope at a point on a curve, again a number or an equation in a different variable. Strictly speaking only indefinite integration is the opposite of (indef.) differentiation and visa versa.